# Why do flight attendants wear gloves during takeoff and landing?

Tags: landing, takeoff, flight-attendant

Last time I was flying the flight attendant put on black leather gloves during while she was seated during takeoff and landing. She took them of as soon as she got up from the seat.

This wasn't the first time I've seen this.

Is this a safety of flight issue?

Edit:
The airline I've seen this was Finnair.
There where three flight attendants on the flight, but only one was sitting near me, so I couldn't see what the others did.

Comment: She was cold? I've never seen this happen and I fly a lot.

Comment: @RonBeyer: If she was just cold, why would she put off the gloves as soon as she got up?

Comment: Because she's got something to do where wearing gloves is a hindrance, for example.

Comment: Company rules may allow her to wear gloves while seated but not while performing duties. Airlines have some [pretty strict dress codes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://unitedafa.org/docs/uniforms/appearance_standards.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjVh9uug7PTAhVB5iYKHbBbBegQFghHMAY&usg=AFQjCNGex3sjlkuWkPwZszFPT0U9Orss-Q&sig2=3DSZVgKDC8Nbi2sFhKKjfQ)

Comment: It might be helpful if you specified the airline(s) where you've seen this. As mentioned it may be something to do with specific company policies. Also, was it one of many attendants or all of them?

Comment: @FreeMan: I've added the information to the question.

Comment: Did they look something like what this Attendant has on? https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/43/8f/b5/438fb50cc551d9cd542a358be6df9db7.jpg

Comment: Flying tactical jets with the US Navy we were required to fly with Nomex gloves while flying ashore. In an accident, such as a crash during landing, if the hands get severely burned they will become useless making survival more difficult. They had leather palms and pilots complained that they became slippery if they found themselves in the drink, and would compromise safety in that environment. Pilots were encouraged to wear their gloves over water, but it was not required. They limited tactile sensation with the controls, and this made them undesirable from a routine operational perspective.

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic. Flight attendants are required crewmembers and are subject to regulations just like any other crewmember. This question is just as much on-topic as asking why any other crewmember would do something.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. During takeoff and landing is when the cabin crew would have to be prepared for quick response to a fire and/or evacuation scenario; gloves could be useful/essential personal protective equipment in such a scenario.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From Finnair's Facebook page, it looks like Flight Attendancts wear gloves for safety reasons during takeoff/landing and galley preparation. Also it seems they do remove them when greeting passengers.

[image]

https://m.facebook.com/Finnair/posts/10151523242117911